# Checking address fields for presence of a Post Office Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, form, e-commerce

I'm just trying to learn how to write jQuery better so I wanted some smart peoples opinions.

The code is checking the billing and shipping address fields to see if it contains a PO Box address by looking for variations of "PO" and then displays a warning message after the input if it does contain it.

The code is duplicated for each one so there has to be a better way to write this.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ferne97/6RnxG/)

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    // Check for PO Box text in address fields on checkout
    var $shipAddress = $('#checkout input[name="user_data[s_address]"]'),
        $billAddress = $('#checkout input[name="user_data[b_address]"]'),
        message = '<div class="message hidden"><p>We <strong>don\'t ship to PO Boxes</strong>. Sorry for the inconvenience.</p></div>';

    $shipAddress.after(message);
    $billAddress.after(message);

    $shipAddress.keyup(function () {
        var $value = $(this).val();

        if ($value === 'po' || $value === 'Po' || $value === 'PO' || $value === 'P.O' || $value === 'p.o') {
            $shipAddress.siblings('.message').removeClass('hidden');
        } else if ($value === '') {
            $shipAddress.siblings('.message').addClass('hidden');
        }
    });

    $billAddress.keyup(function () {
        var $value = $(this).val();

        if ($value === 'po' || $value === 'Po' || $value === 'PO' || $value === 'P.O' || $value === 'p.o') {
            $billAddress.siblings('.message').removeClass('hidden');
        } else if ($value === '') {
            $billAddress.siblings('.message').addClass('hidden');
        }
    });

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Just so you know, there is a stack overflow question with a more complete PO box matching expression. It may help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680050/po-box-regular-expression-validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's 2 obvious places to clean this up a bit.  The first is the duplicated keyup handler and the second is the check for PO.

Most jQuery functions can be called on a collection of elements.  Since you are calling the same code on both your shipping address and billing address, we can combine them like so:

```
var $addresses = $('#checkout input[name="user_data[s_address]"]')
                 .add($('#checkout input[name="user_data[b_address]"]));
```

For the PO check, you can just use a regular expression:

```
//p, optional period, o
if(/p\.?o/i.test($value)) { ... }
```

So the whole thing becomes:

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    // Check for PO Box text in address fields on checkout
    var $addresses = $('#checkout input[name="user_data[s_address]"]')
        .add($('#checkout input[name="user_data[b_address]"]')),
        message = "<div class='message hidden'><p>We <strong>don't ship to PO Boxes</strong>. Sorry for the inconvenience.</p></div>";

    $addresses.after(message);

    $addresses.keyup(function () {
        var $value = $(this).val();

        if(/p\.?o/i.test($value)) { 
            $(this).siblings('.message').removeClass('hidden');
        } else if ($value === '') {
            $(this).siblings('.message').addClass('hidden');
        }
    });

}(jQuery));
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/6RnxG/7/

Comment: Thanks, that cleans it up a lot. Those were the exact spots I was looking to clean up.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to drch's answser, this section

```
if(/p\.?o/i.test($value)) { 
    $(this).siblings('.message').removeClass('hidden');
} else if ($value === '') {
    $(this).siblings('.message').addClass('hidden');
}
```

could be rewritten as

```
var showMessage = ! /p\.?o/i.test($value);
 $(this).siblings('.message').toggleClass('hidden', showMessage);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a good solution, BUT, what happens when the address is something like pollock road? It will throw an error.